# Extract a single list of data points from a list of multiple lines

Tags: list-manipulation

So I have a list of 50 lines that ive acquired using the EdgeDetect function on a .bmb from an experiment ive run. The list looks like:

```
lines = {{{{938.0182717999902`, 
  641.693689525029`}, {934.881599312007`, 
  649.5937708982256`}}, {{931.006886238616`, 
  659.3526949474685`}, {899.8246715051359`, 
  737.8887980104239`}}, {{892.075245358354`, 
  757.4066461089099`}, {887.4624916995551`, 
  769.0244128341991`}}, {{884.1413090652201`, 
  777.3892048764073`}, {881.5581670162927`, 
  783.8951542425693`}}, {{944.1071066296046`, 
  626.3582374476471`}, {943.0000457514928`, 
  629.1465014617165`}}}, {{{510.34613621146997`, 
  794.0249603966897`}, {506.98736124699525`, 
  787.3190949985463`}}, {{501.16548464190583`, 
  775.6955949750976`}, {468.92124498294885`, 
  711.3192871529201`}}, {{459.96451174434975`, 
  693.4369794245375`}, {453.02304348443533`, 
  679.578190935041`}}}, {{{936.0000959307632`, 
  663.7025592719378`}, {930.8499743185687`, 
  673.9848862157578`}}, {{926.1476893683041`, 
  683.3730977731587`}, {917.8627111225999`, 
  699.9142324219126`}}, {{908.0103045601409`, 
  719.5847709231335`}, {881.8118598372382`, 771.8905210286528`}}, 
{{877.1095748869737`, 781.2787325860536`}, {873.750799922499`, 
  787.9845979841971`}}}, {{{534.1400686554078`, 
  420.12961807233677`}, {546.6156584942452`, 
  414.9711630543011`}}, {{563.2497782793616`, 
  408.0932230302535`}, {638.5653761953058`, 
  376.9514390324826`}}, {{655.1994959804224`, 
  370.07349900843496`}, {668.1371447021796`, 
  364.72399010084246`}}}, {{{498.2954016379278`, 
  777.8325788373728`}, {493.06449257585854`, 
  765.3871945369841`}}, {{486.0899471597662`, 
  748.7933488031325`}, {453.92954329667367`, 
  672.2772823637057`}}, {{446.95499788058135`, 
  655.6834366298541`}, {442.8865130545274`, 
  646.0036932851073`}}}, {{{725.057713368362`, 
  367.92360979187123`}, {739.3015594484755`, 
  374.03612554612766`}}, {{755.3833211518296`, 
  380.93735301061076`}, {827.5215093640177`, 
  411.8942876370063`}}, {{846.3601445022324`, 
  419.9785826668293`}, {855.5497226184347`, 
  423.9221412179625`}}}, {{{533.9548792391797`, 
  812.3829053385664`}, {542.7157969469038`, 
  816.0566392590467`}}, {{559.3154304983809`, 
  823.0173982662726`}, {630.7860749561295`, 
  852.9873328807173`}}, {{651.9967178274613`, 
  861.881636056617`}, {662.1409383311417`, 
  866.1354332276994`}}, {{635.3970842759842`, 
  854.9208770493912`}, {635.8581852079697`, 
  855.1142314662585`}}}, {{{728.3668171708799`, 
  865.1339222802936`}, {742.04078745569`, 
  858.9676805845658`}}, {{763.919139911386`, 
  849.1016938714012`}, {832.288991335436`, 
  818.2704853927619`}}, {{850.065152705689`, 
  810.2543711883156`}, {859.636931905056`, 
  805.9380020013061`}}}, {{{936.977320256363`, 
  570.7964241338441`}, {929.8989204686031`, 
  555.340154970665`}}, {{920.9468266193772`, 
  535.792520440762`}, {890.9677216359235`, 
  470.33067457318015`}}, {{885.3466394515258`, 
  458.0565784730085`}, {880.766498412387`, 
  448.055463132128`}}, {{923.0287089098949`, 
  540.3384819593441`}, {923.0287089098949`, 
  540.3384819593441`}}}, {{{441.90044115645924`, 
  590.6879443671335`}, {446.04444798644636`, 
  580.4983807163669`}}, {{453.0139140186973`, 
  563.3613873037143`}, {483.9056012967825`, 
  487.4028219070916`}}, {{491.81688706312127`, 
  467.9500185738103`}, {496.1492578399259`, 
  457.2972929389182`}}}, {{{518.3373721214956`, 
  801.0986706095794`}, {525.0515867862819`, 
  804.4407240853889`}}, {{534.4514873169825`, 
  809.119598951522`}, {596.6698765440015`, 
  840.0892944940225`}}, {{612.3363774285026`, 
  847.8874192709111`}, {626.6600353800465`, 
  855.0171333526379`}}}, {{{453.85378853766207`, 
  551.048222608234`}, {460.99539838630477`, 
  536.7304920349285`}}, {{469.92241069710815`, 
  518.8333288182964`}, {501.16695378491994`, 
  456.1932575600845`}}, {{505.8536352480917`, 
  446.79724687135274`}, {509.201264864643`, 
  440.0858106651157`}}}, {{{570.0541850855988`, 
  831.8088263684696`}, {585.7045911653198`, 
  837.035181651057`}}, {{609.4173276497457`, 
  844.9539017761894`}, {663.4823668342368`, 
  863.0085836614912`}}, {{678.1842634545808`, 
  867.9181901390732`}, {684.8238296702201`, 
  870.1354317741103`}}, {{588.5501195434509`, 
  837.9854280660728`}, {588.5501195434509`, 
  837.9854280660728`}}, {{606.097544541926`, 
  843.8452809586707`}, {606.5717992716146`, 
  844.0036553611734`}}, {{666.3278952123678`, 
  863.958830076507`}, {666.8021499420564`, 
  864.1172044790097`}}}, {{{706.7768745895008`, 
  869.1191506798796`}, {715.2244069551125`, 
  866.0144450687233`}}, {{726.0184760889495`, 
  862.0473212322458`}, {788.436354123746`, 
  839.1069964387025`}}, {{813.3096438669356`, 
  829.965363250298`}, {826.4502497689981`, 
  825.1358211884993`}}, {{791.2521982456166`, 
  838.072094568317`}, {791.7215055992616`, 
  837.8996109232528`}}, {{810.4937997450651`, 
  831.0002651206834`}, {810.4937997450651`, 
  831.0002651206834`}}}, {{{516.1366250381197`, 
  433.24471622944947`}, {524.6271842378811`, 
  428.9832136217594`}}, {{534.0114865113014`, 
  424.2731317922072`}, {596.5735016674372`, 
  392.87258626185945`}}, {{612.2140054564711`, 
  385.02244987927253`}, {628.3013807823346`, 
  376.9480238857545`}}}, {{{703.5649354181747`, 
  363.9096398724151`}, {709.6951928983599`, 
  366.07064501508216`}}, {{723.3703826618499`, 
  370.8913487948781`}, {783.7298409282886`, 
  392.16893789190834`}}, {{808.2508708490292`, 
  400.81295846257683`}, {825.6985267541716`, 
  406.96351156093715`}}}, {{{869.9015661351866`, 
  435.0980688916539`}, {863.2209981930705`, 
  431.68925502598603`}}, {{850.7506047011202`, 
  425.3261358100727`}, {793.297720398921`, 
  396.010336565329`}}, {{777.7097285339833`, 
  388.05643754543735`}, {763.9032214536098`, 
  381.0115555563904`}}}, {{{940.1508355287278`, 
  627.7202241366501`}, {936.3395098709427`, 
  639.6250045516897`}}, {{933.5953553973375`, 
  648.1964464505181`}, {920.941754213491`, 
  687.7203174284493`}}, {{914.0813680294777`, 
  709.1489221755206`}, {908.7455121085786`, 
  725.815614756576`}}, {{904.1719213192365`, 
  740.1013512546233`}, {900.6655017140743`, 
  751.0537492364597`}}, {{920.0270360556226`, 
  690.5774647280589`}, {920.0270360556226`, 
  690.5774647280589`}}}, {{{944.0200389113847`, 
  601.5961457494698`}, {940.9504455220562`, 
  593.1357913582997`}}, {{936.0049895059158`, 
  579.505220394748`}, {913.6651709502471`, 
  517.9326412145658`}}, {{905.9911874769258`, 
  496.78175523664066`}, {900.0225336643426`, 
  480.33106614269883`}}, {{907.0143852733686`, 
  499.60187336703063`}, {907.0143852733686`, 
  499.60187336703063`}}}, {{{930.1189968883771`, 
  550.6839876157549`}, {923.876270338755`, 
  539.2809895351339`}}, {{919.074172992892`, 
  530.5094525500409`}, {910.9106075049248`, 
  515.5978396753827`}}, {{901.0663079459055`, 
  497.616188855942`}, {878.9766601549354`, 
  457.2671187245141`}}, {{873.2141433398997`, 
  446.74127434240245`}, {870.572989799675`, 
  441.9169290006013`}}}, {{{575.1148327125937`, 
  399.08775168869727`}, {590.7738999399169`, 
  393.88740424163416`}}, {{608.331035922067`, 
  388.0567116494725`}, {662.9005126233444`, 
  369.934288727889`}}, {{677.610545473254`, 
  365.04911385337516`}, {683.7792689264419`, 
  363.00049213180483`}}, {{674.7634423410135`, 
  365.994631571023`}, {674.7634423410135`, 
  365.994631571023`}}}, {{{438.8541506243913`, 
  609.5816272118383`}, {441.0548395332715`, 
  602.936556232057`}}, {{445.9277935457918`, 
  588.2224704911126`}, {465.1052254660333`, 
  530.3154233815897`}}, {{471.86448425759374`, 
  509.9055625151185`}, {477.0518223999541`, 
  494.24218091991975`}}}, {{{922.9183163334442`, 
  700.4962389643329`}, {917.047410463922`, 
  710.3847405834464`}}, {{910.9212478174642`, 
  720.7031770555648`}, {905.050341947942`, 
  730.5916786746783`}}, {{895.0953276474478`, 
  747.3591379418708`}, {874.6747854925881`, 
  781.7539261822656`}}, {{870.3354202846804`, 
  789.0628186833494`}, {867.0170821845156`, 
  794.6519717724135`}}, {{863.1882305304795`, 
  801.1009945674875`}, {861.4014330919292`, 
  804.1105385385221`}}}, {{{768.4729337235327`, 
  851.1454738700766`}, {783.9129754458769`, 
  842.9080524524078`}}, {{800.6764493158506`, 
  833.964566341796`}, {854.0548792702407`, 
  805.4866237264264`}}, {{864.2011924020669`, 
  800.0734610805298`}, {869.053776943375`, 
  797.4845572064053`}}}, {{{463.25224269276856`, 
  705.8644674132026`}, {460.84233857240315`, 
  696.1591924490068`}}, {{456.98649197981854`, 
  680.6307525062936`}, {452.88965497519746`, 
  664.1317850671606`}}, {{451.08222688492333`, 
  656.8528288440137`}, {442.88855287568106`, 
  623.854893965748`}}, {{440.11716313726083`, 
  612.6938277569228`}, {438.91221107707815`, 
  607.841190274825`}}, {{452.04618853306954`, 
  660.7349388296922`}, {451.92569332705125`, 
  660.2496750814825`}}, {{442.1655816395714`, 
  620.9433114764894`}, {441.9245912275349`, 
  619.9727839800697`}}}, {{{509.19986827942984`, 
  786.9329244529322`}, {481.86390053587496`, 
  740.3631395326287`}}, {{473.00502210046363`, 
  725.2710796047526`}, {466.93036260189587`, 
  714.9222385113518`}}}, {{{463.10906833362026`, 
  705.8215365709461`}, {440.8338320897309`, 
  638.9330932471631`}}}, {{{704.5242626870805`, 
  366.9616871104964`}, {752.7463203658676`, 
  380.17657088689504`}}, {{770.106261130231`, 
  384.93392904639853`}, {784.5728784338672`, 
  388.89839417931813`}}, {{755.6396438265949`, 
  380.969463913479`}, {755.6396438265949`, 
  380.969463913479`}}}, {{{509.00073948327554`, 
  792.601812165756`}, {514.6036265393997`, 
  795.896908012058`}}, {{523.2234527795906`, 
  800.9662862371381`}, {569.3395231646122`, 
  828.0874597413163`}}, {{580.9762885888699`, 
  834.9311203451743`}, {591.3200800770991`, 
  841.0143742152703`}}}, {{{465.8535220251778`, 
  519.6253628345503`}, {473.1521455469121`, 
  507.09619308200945`}}, {{480.9541224149729`, 
  493.7029426568794`}, {508.13520311660403`, 
  447.0425863370716`}}, {{512.9170599067057`, 
  438.83381994747583`}, {516.188856657828`, 
  433.2172955756473`}}}, {{{605.3593557193665`, 
  846.892157696029`}, {617.9307161416536`, 
  850.2028822591651`}}, {{635.3372151878974`, 
  854.7869624235071`}, {678.3699489411111`, 
  866.1198272742419`}}, {{689.0072539138157`, 
  868.9212095968953`}, {693.3588786753767`, 
  870.067229637981`}}}, {{{508.21210834329105`, 
  441.32327256964817`}, {513.7874310508546`, 
  437.98174945787315`}}, {{522.7937215784572`, 
  432.58390443115974`}, {565.6808193289459`, 
  406.879880494429`}}, {{580.262432564112`, 
  398.14051235594053`}, {588.8398521142097`, 
  392.9997075685944`}}}, {{{945.0453081544204`, 
  615.3485245126913`}, {942.9491658930333`, 
  608.1474004601544`}}, {{940.1543095445172`, 
  598.5459017234383`}, {924.9223424451045`, 
  546.217733608336`}}, {{920.1710866526272`, 
  529.8951857559189`}, {915.8390593124273`, 
  515.012862714009`}}, {{924.0838855405497`, 
  543.3372839873211`}, {924.0838855405497`, 
  543.3372839873211`}}}, {{{891.0325764337999`, 
  769.5939985368944`}, {886.0684592873286`, 
  774.529334488591`}}, {{881.104342140857`, 
  779.4646704402875`}, {857.3474957970293`, 
  803.0837782091207`}}, {{850.2558998734986`, 
  810.1342581401157`}, {845.2917827270271`, 
  815.0695940918122`}}}, {{{442.88828917567344`, 
  604.4194667372232`}, {454.07330507843335`, 
  560.315663961782`}}, {{458.1294097464672`, 
  544.3219772410176`}, {461.2022163131595`, 
  532.2055479071053`}}, {{438.9550967703073`, 
  619.9284962846309`}, {440.0613071343165`, 
  615.5665817244225`}}, {{461.9396898891656`, 
  529.2976048669664`}, {461.9396898891656`, 
  529.2976048669664`}}}, {{{912.968724098682`, 
  724.7785143520076`}, {907.0206200325399`, 
  733.4312629337211`}}, {{901.9222451187039`, 
  740.8479045751898`}, {895.9741410525619`, 
  749.5006531569032`}}, {{888.8930647833452`, 
  759.8015443256098`}, {871.048752584919`, 
  785.7597900707502`}}}, {{{799.38719576434`, 
  838.0383521385287`}, {810.861653119809`, 
  830.9259103357774`}}, {{823.6110501814413`, 
  823.0231972216093`}, {863.1341810725012`, 
  798.5247865676884`}}, {{872.9087188197525`, 
  792.4660398468262`}, {875.8835781341334`, 
  790.6220734535203`}}}, {{{492.05116674564863`, 
  464.5314947377653`}, {497.00707777761914`, 
  459.5879185177407`}}, {{504.08695068043426`, 
  452.52566677484845`}, {527.8045249048648`, 
  428.86712343615943`}}, {{534.5304041625392`, 
  422.1579842804117`}, {539.8403088396504`, 
  416.86129547324265`}}}, {{{892.1352674415075`, 
  465.8555431860126`}, {886.8606781391678`, 
  460.5236853773643`}}, {{881.9377281236507`, 
  455.54728475595925`}, {859.4328137670013`, 
  432.79802477239326`}}, {{856.9713387592428`, 
  430.3098244616907`}, {853.4549458910163`, 
  426.7552525892586`}}, {{847.828717301854`, 
  421.06793759336705`}, {842.9057672863369`, 
  416.091536971962`}}}, {{{856.1287152741202`, 
  429.5556949687151`}, {825.373670744188`, 
  410.8440078197195`}}, {{810.85045527172`, 
  402.00793333269377`}, {799.3173135729954`, 
  394.9910506518204`}}, {{874.0691579165806`, 
  440.4708458056292`}, {871.0790841428371`, 
  438.6516539994768`}}}, {{{706.7688454705797`, 
  866.1155780183958`}, {715.8791630173511`, 
  863.422603046921`}}, {{727.3869325501149`, 
  860.020950451374`}, {764.7871835315974`, 
  848.965579515846`}}, {{778.2129146531553`, 
  844.9969848210411`}, {794.5155881579041`, 
  840.1779769773493`}}, {{693.3431143490219`, 
  870.0841727132007`}, {697.6585279238083`, 
  868.8085529898706`}}, {{723.0715189753284`, 
  861.2965701747041`}, {724.5099901669239`, 
  860.8713636002608`}}}, {{{494.062310857749`, 
  770.3689753167482`}, {497.9497825454709`, 
  774.259677551199`}}, {{505.0179128867835`, 
  781.3336816138369`}, {528.6961495301806`, 
  805.0315952236737`}}, {{534.7040603202963`, 
  811.0444986769159`}, {539.6517515592151`, 
  815.9963015207622`}}}, {{{517.1634841965435`, 
  795.6789694714448`}, {551.4209216971924`, 
  819.1028456641062`}}, {{561.326686757621`, 
  825.876014683671`}, {570.4069713963472`, 
  832.0847529516053`}}}, {{{602.0142539261672`, 
  387.243783784461`}, {614.5965454069391`, 
  383.97484801071255`}}, {{629.1145740385991`, 
  380.2029990410027`}, {656.698828438753`, 
  373.0364859985541`}}, {{669.7650542072471`, 
  369.6418219258152`}, {680.4116085371311`, 
  366.875799348028`}}, {{691.058162867015`, 
  364.10977677024084`}, {695.897505744235`, 
  362.85249378033757`}}, {{660.086368452807`, 
  372.1563879056217`}, {664.441777042305`, 
  371.0248332147088`}}}, {{{905.9199002037807`, 
  493.45496358432825`}, {900.0438762802721`, 
  484.75310499835047`}}, {{893.0486097046667`, 
  474.3937495388531`}, {872.0628099778505`, 
  443.315683160361`}}}, {{{935.6213140090215`, 
  664.6453250456834`}, {936.2842795249042`, 
  658.1792229180681`}}, {{938.3751707673033`, 
  637.7861315925124`}, {941.1290275255852`, 
  610.9269381393415`}}, {{942.148974473097`, 
  600.979088712241`}, {942.8119399889797`, 
  594.5129865846258`}}}, {{{876.1076320107848`, 
  447.8418696405944`}, {858.4831529239871`, 
  433.06426033059324`}}, {{855.8011669759961`, 
  430.8154936964627`}, {845.4563640337453`, 
  422.1416795362446`}}, {{835.8778427909205`, 
  414.1103701286353`}, {830.8970117446515`, 
  409.93408923667846`}}}, {{{477.96977243615703`, 
  739.5010003762118`}, {484.14074367653006`, 
  748.606993674611`}}, {{493.1167018443452`, 
  761.8520748359189`}, {514.1541038001619`, 
  792.895233807734`}}, {{518.9225815768137`, 
  799.9316831746788`}, {521.7275685042559`, 
  804.0707710375876`}}}, {{{478.0161120665802`, 
  492.38506823471084`}, {483.9210169803439`, 
  483.70278178703984`}}, {{492.9189673251266`, 
  470.47263100963653`}, {510.0713101698685`, 
  445.25265609021153`}}, {{490.95066568720534`, 
  473.3667264921935`}, {490.95066568720534`, 
  473.3667264921935`}}, {{512.0396118077897`, 
  442.35856060765457`}, {512.3207977560642`, 
  441.94511839586073`}}}, {{{485.1229000153161`, 
  477.42071111685743`}, {489.811587837629`, 
  471.5669767100968`}}, {{500.1267010467176`, 
  458.68876101522335`}, {517.3185563951986`, 
  437.22506819043406`}}, {{497.9386467296382`, 
  461.42050373837833`}, {497.9386467296382`, 
  461.42050373837833`}}, {{523.8827193464367`, 
  429.0298400209691`}, {526.3833528516702`, 
  425.9078483373635`}}}};
```

What I would like to be able to do is take each of the 50 lines in this list. extract their beginning and end points and place that into a single list which should have 100 points which will hopefully make it easier for me to do some of the image analysis im looking to do.

Is it possible to do this via an inbuilt method that im not finding in the documentation or is there something I need to write for this.

In response to those asking for a smaller data set I reran my edge detect with much fewer features. Heres a list of 5 relevant lines for expirimentation

```
lines2={{{{938.018, 641.694}, {934.882, 649.594}}, {{931.007, 
659.353}, {899.825, 737.889}}, {{892.075, 757.407}, {887.462, 
769.024}}, {{884.141, 777.389}, {881.558, 783.895}}, {{944.107, 
626.358}, {943., 629.147}}}, {{{510.346, 794.025}, {506.987, 
787.319}}, {{501.165, 775.696}, {468.921, 711.319}}, {{459.965, 
693.437}, {453.023, 679.578}}}, {{{936., 663.703}, {930.85, 
673.985}}, {{926.148, 683.373}, {917.863, 699.914}}, {{908.01, 
719.585}, {881.812, 771.891}}, {{877.11, 781.279}, {873.751, 
787.985}}, {{870.168, 795.138}, {868.825, 797.82}}}, {{{534.14, 
420.13}, {546.616, 414.971}}, {{563.25, 408.093}, {638.565, 
376.951}}, {{655.199, 370.073}, {668.137, 364.724}}}, {{{498.295, 
777.833}, {493.064, 765.387}}, {{486.09, 748.793}, {453.93, 
672.277}}, {{446.955, 655.683}, {442.887, 646.004}}}};
```

An example of part of what im looking for is what happens if i extract a single element of this list of lines:

```
ListPlot[lines[[1]]]
```

i get a nice line of data points but if i use:

```
ListPlot[{lines[[1]],lines[[2]]}]
```

i get nothing. additionally, to do what im looking for i would need to plot all 50 of these one one plot and then strip out the excess data points that arent the endpoints for each line

Comment: Do us all a favour, and yourself, and post a smaller representative dataset for us to experiment with.  You're probably just looking for an expression such as `lines[[All,{1,-1}]]`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I added a list of 5 of the lines above.

im confused as to what the expression you posted does. When i run it, it seems to just return the original lines list

Comment: Now execute `lines2[[1]]` and tell us what the first and last points of that are.  is the first point `{938.018, 641.694}` and the last point `{943., 629.147}` ?  From where i sit your sets have one too many levels (or sets of `{}` if you like to think that way).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark yes i get the same points for that and i agree about the {} but thats the way that edge detect is exporting my data for whatever reason. Is there a way to just strip those out? would that help?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this using a looped join function like so:

```
Points = lines[[1]];
Do[Points = Join[Points, lines[[i]]], {i, 2, 50, 1}];
```

This joins each individual line segment set into one large list.

Comment: `Join @@ lines` is easier and more efficient. But what you asked for in your question sounded more like `Join @@ lines[[All, {-1, 1}]]`.